# Filter out really unique rows

Tags: sql

```
A | B
=====
1 | 2
3 | 4
2 | 1
```

How can I filter this table and get only unique rows? Something like that:

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

Comment: Why not just 1, 2, 3, 4 in a single column? If they are similar if order reversed, then they must be serving the same purpose.

Comment: @Gurwinder-Singh legacy code for source -> target class. In some cases they are similar in some not

Comment: Are you looking for a general/ansi SQL or specific brand? (mysql/sql-server/etc) please specify which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select a, b
from t
where a <= b
union all
select a, b
from t
where a > b and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a);
```

Note:  This assumes that there are no actual duplicates in your data and you only one to keep one pair, regardless of the ordering.

Comment: Thank you, and what if varchars instead of integers in columns?

Comment: What if?  Nothing would change.

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct

```
select distinct least(a,b) as a, greatest(a,b) as b
from the_table;
```

Or if your DBMS does not support `least()` and `greatest()`

```
select distinct 
         case when a < b then a else b end as a,
         case when a > b then a else b end as b
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version that omits the subquery and handles actual duplicates by leaning on `UNION`:

```
SELECT a, b FROM test WHERE a <= b
UNION
SELECT b, a FROM test WHERE a > b;
```